# How to save changes on multiple contenteditable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I want to make my photo captions editable and then save the changes in localstorage. It works for the first photo but when I want to edit another, changes are saved to this first photo and not the one I edited.
Here's part of my code where I display photos with captions:

```html
<div class="gallery">
   <a href="<?=$path1; ?>">
      <img src="<?= $path1; ?>">
   </a>
   <div id="contenteditable">
      <p id="caption-photo" contenteditable> <?=pathinfo($path1, PATHINFO_FILENAME)?></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And it is my js code to save the changes:

```js
const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
        editables.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
            localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
        })
        });
        for (var key in localStorage) {
            if (key.includes("dataStorage-")) {
                const id = key.replace("dataStorage-","");
                document.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do all your `p` blocks have `id="caption-photo"`? ... Because this part: `localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);` , where you're using `el.id`, if it is the same for all of them, then the value will be overwritten every single time ... if so, you also should not have more than 1 element with the same id ---- In this case you can change the Id of each element and add a number to the end like - `id="caption-photo1"` ... caption-photo2 and so on

Comment: ahh yes, they all do, but I upload them from directory in `foreach` so I don't know how to change that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay lemme open your mind a bit ... also pardon me for the many answers, I just like comprehensive answers:
Create a new `php` file with the name `update_file.php` and put it within the same directory. Then put the `php` code that handles the requests in this file.
**Why is this important?** Because we are depending on the responseText being received from the php file which will tell us whether the request was successful or not. And, when the php that handles the request is within the same file as the `html`, the request will return a response containing the `html` content of the page --- You can experiment this yourself and see that if you put the code below within the same file, the `responseText` will be the whole code in the page, and that's not what we want, we want either 0 or 1 ... ok, enough said:
Put this in `update_file.php` in the same directory as the current file:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["old_name"]) && isset($_GET["new_name"]) && isset($_GET["directory"]) && isset($_GET["extension"])){
        $old_name = $_GET["old_name"];
        $new_name = $_GET["new_name"];
        // The new values from the GET request
        $directory = $_GET["directory"];
        $extension = $_GET["extension"];
        // echo $directory;
        // echo $extension;
        // Concatenate the values with the directories

        // 1 thing to note, if the image is in the current directory,
        // the value you will receive for $directory will be "."
        // So the method below ensures flexibility with different directories
        $dot = ".";
        // $dot is added before the extension
        $slash = "/";
        // $slash is added after the directory name
        // if ".", it will be "./' -- for current directory
        // if "some/directory" , it will be "some/directory/"
        // Then add to the file name and the extension
        $full_oldname = $directory . $slash . $old_name . $dot . $extension;
        $full_newname = $directory . $slash . $new_name . $dot . $extension;
        echo rename($full_oldname, $full_newname);
    }

?>
```

Then this is your current file:

```
<?php
    $some_records = ["record1.jpeg", "uploads/record2.jpeg", "images/subdirectory1/record3.jpeg", "images/record4.jpg", "images/subdirectory2/record5.jpg"];
    // Assuming your directory has subdirectories
    $counter = 1;

?>

<div class="gallery">
    <?php foreach ($some_records as $path) {
        echo '<a href="' . $path . '">
            <img src="' . $path . '">
        </a>
        <div id="contenteditable">
            <p id="caption-photo' . $counter . '" contenteditable>' . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="directory-"' . $counter . '" value="' . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '" />
            <input type="hidden" name="extension-"' . $counter . '" value="' . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) . '" />
        </div>';
        // Note the 2 hidden inputs above
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
</div>

<script>
    function update_file(old_name, new_name, directory, extension) {
        // The function has been updated with the new parameters
        var update = new XMLHttpRequest();
        update.open("GET", "update_file.php?old_name=" + old_name + "&new_name=" + new_name + "&directory=" + directory + "&extension=" + extension, true);
        // The XHR request has also been updated with the new values
        update.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
                if (this.responseText != null) {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    // This will either be 0 or 1, if correct values have been passed to it
                    if(this.responseText == 1){
                        console.log("Renamed successfully!");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Error renaming!");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Not sent!!");
                }
            }
        };
        update.send();
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
        editables.forEach(el => {
            var curr = el.innerHTML;
            // The next element after "el" is the first hidden input with the directory
            var dir = el.nextElementSibling.value;
            // The next element after the above hidden input is the second hidden input with the extension
            // Note the 2 ".nextElementSibling" accessors
            var ext = el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.value;
            // To get the value of any input(that can lie within a form control) use "[element].value'

            console.log(ext);
            console.log(dir);
            el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
                localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
                console.log(el.innerHTML);
                update_file(curr, el.innerHTML, dir, ext);
            })
        });
        for(var i = 1; i < editables.length+1; i++){
            console.log("dataStorage-caption-photo" + i + " => " + localStorage.getItem("dataStorage-caption-photo" + i));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also read the comments, the main points here are:

1. How to add the hidden input elements with the respective values
2. How to access the values with javascript
3. How to add them to the XHR request and then capture them with php
4. Finally, how to concatenate them and get your full path

Hope this helps

---

Here is some developer tools you can be using, I'm not sure which browser you are using but you might find such a similar thing, go to the console tab then click on settings and enable logging of `XMLHttpRequests`
[image: Options to be logged]
[image: Enable logging of XHRequests]
You will be able to see the requests right after you remove focus on any contenteditable element and confirm whether they are being sent

Comment: It helps a lot, I can say I was close but my attempts with nextElementSibling weren't useful haha. Not sure why I get "Error renaming" because all logs are correct and I don't see any errors in console or network tab

Comment: And again thank you so much for your help and patience! I/m doing my best to understand every step but it's not always easy haha

Comment: No worries, just take your time and understand them and it'll work out, and if you get stuck with another issue, don't hesitate to ask for help

Comment: my this.responseText log doesn't show anything, neither 1 nor any other value and the "Error renaming" still occurs, do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: For starters, you can first check whether the XHRequests are being sent, see edited above

Comment: So I get the message: XHR finished loading

Comment: Ok that's progress, it will also show you the actual request and the parameters that have been passed to the url, next try commenting out the whole js condition that checks `... if(this.responseText == 1){ ...` and leave out the outer one that just logs the responseText. Then on the `update_file.php`, echo the values for: `$full_oldname` and `$full_newname`  right after the one that says `echo rename( ... )` .. All this values that are being "echoed" will be part of the responseText and they will be logged, this should tell you the actual values for the old name and the new name and match them

Comment: Ok, so the problem is probably that there are spaces between directory, name and extension so it basically looks like `/images/subdirectory /image .jpg`

Comment: You can use `php`'s `trim()` function to remove values from the beginning and the end of the string: **Syntax**: trim([$my_string], [optional values to trim]) --- As for this case you can use: `$directory = trim($directory, " ");` to remove the whitespace from the end and/or beginning - (there's also rtrim and ltrim for right and left only respectively` Also you can use it as so: `$directory = trim($directory);` -- without arguments and it will strip any form of "\t, \n, whitespaces" and such ... also do this for `$extension` -- might also be from the new name from the input - also check that

Comment: Yes I've already done this and the values looks okay... but error still appears when I uncomment that part with `responseText == 1` and I'm not able to  make it work :(

Comment: Other than the part of the error in the responseText, have you checked the files whether they have actually been renamed? cause while I was preparing this code in some instances the file names were changing but I was getting errors, first see if the names have been changed, if not, then double check the `rename()` function again

Comment: no, they don't change names so it must be something with `rename`, I checked it and everything should be ok, but `if(rename($full_oldname, $full_newname)){..` is not executed even though I don't have any error

Comment: Try this, create a php file let's say `test.php` and in this file just put the rename() function along with the values of actual paths to images in your directory, and see whether it renames them, this should clear a few things on whether the files are getting renamed or not

Comment: I added full paths to my values and finally it works. However I still get this error renaming message but files change names and after refreshing show up with new ones

Comment: The error might only be from the responseText ... ensure that the only value being "echoed" in `update_file.php` is this: `echo rename($full_oldname, $full_newname)` and nothing else at all, since this function returns either 1 or 0, and this is what the Javascript condition depends on so it can output either "Error renaming" (if it gets a value that is not 1) or "Renamed successfully" (if it gets 1) **POINTER** -- when you echo the value in the `php` file, that is what will be received in the `responseText` in `Javascript`

Comment: That's the point! I had `$full_oldname` and `$full_newname` echoed... now it outputs "Renamed successfully"

Comment: So I think that's it, thank you so so much for your help and patience! I am really grateful

Comment: You're welcome, thanks too coz this was also a learning process for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion: suppose your `foreach` loop is:

```
<?=
    #Other php stuff here
    #You can define a counter variable:
    $counter = 1;
?>
<div class="gallery">
<?= foreach($some_records as $your_value){ ?>
    <a href="<?=$path1; ?>">
    <img src="<?= $path1; ?>">
    </a>
<div id="contenteditable">
    #Which you can append to the caption-photo
    #So the id of the first will be: caption-photo1
    <p id="caption-photo<?= $counter ?>" contenteditable> <?=pathinfo($path1, PATHINFO_FILENAME)?></p>
<?=
        $counter++;
        #At the end of each loop, increase the value of counter by 1
    }
?>
</div>
```

Also don't mind the `foreach` loop, I'm sure it doesn't match yours, but just get the aspect of appending a number to the id so that you can get different values

---

Okay since that doesn't work, here is a snippet of the above but without using the `short_open_tags`(`<?= ... =>`), Instead I just used the `php`(`<?php ... ?>`) tags as they are:
Try running the code as it is first and check the logs

```
<?php
    $some_records = ["record1.jpg", "record2.jpg", "record3.jpg", "record4.jpg", "record5.jpg"];
    $counter = 1;
?>

<div class="gallery">
    <?php foreach ($some_records as $path) {
        echo '<a href="' . $path . '">
            <img src="' . $path . '">
        </a>
        <div id="contenteditable">
            <p id="caption-photo' . $counter . '" contenteditable>' . pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '</p>
        </div>';
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
        editables.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
                localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
                console.log(el.innerHTML);
                //When you change the value, it is logged
            })
        });
        /* The loop below does not work as expected */
        // for (var key in localStorage) {
        //     if (key.includes("dataStorage-")) {
        //         const id = key.replace("dataStorage-", "");
        //         document.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
        //  ---- The above direct way of selecting the element does not work
        //         console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
        //     }
        // }
        /* 1 is added to editables.length because the counter starts
        from 1 and not 0 */
        for(var i = 1; i < editables.length+1; i++){
            console.log("dataStorage-caption-photo" + i + " => " + localStorage.getItem("dataStorage-caption-photo" + i));
            //This logs all the values associated with the elements
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is how the elements are set in the above code:
As you can see the counter is working ok.
[image: Id of the elements]

And based on your loop that is commented out, this part returns an error because that "direct" method of accessing elements does not work:
[image: Error in console]

Comment: thank you, I tried and it also didn't work, now any of change isn't saved haha

Comment: So I suppose my counter doesn't work properly because all of my captions are set as 1, I don't have any idea why

Comment: Problem might be the position of the place you define it or the position where you increase its value by 1: ... **1**.The `$counter` variable has to be initialized outside of the loop(`$counter = 1;`) ... **2**. The incrementing function has to be inside the loop(`$counter++;`) ... or else if the counter is outside the loop, it would remain 1 all through --- Check properly where the closing bracket for the `foreach` loop is and where the increment is

Comment: Okay, my `$counter` was one bracket too far so now I see in console that everything works fine. But what about resreshing page? When I do it, everything come back to initial state instead of staying changed

Comment: That's because the content is being loaded from your directory which has not changed ... if you'd like to change the names of the files, use `php`'s `rename([old name], [new name])` function, such that when the "editable" is blurred, the rename function takes action with those 2 parameters ... This then brings you to a place where you need to implement `AJAX` so that you can get the value from `Javascript` then capture it with `php` using `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to assist you:
Place this one before everything in your `php` file

```
if(isset($_GET["old_name"]) && isset($_GET["new_name"])){
    $old_name = $_GET["old_name"];
    // The same variables in the `GET` request
    $new_name = $_GET["new_name"];
    // Also remember the extension of the files
    $ext = ".jpeg";
    // As for rename you have to give the full path
    // If your folder is uploads/, and the file is oldname.jpg
    // Then it should be rename("uploads/" . $old_name  $ext, "uploads/" . $new_name . $ext);
    // Just provide the full path to the file you are renaming
    // If the images are within the same directory, its ok as it is
    echo rename($old_name . $ext, $new_name . $ext);
    // returns true if successful
    // returns false if not successful
    // This is the "responseText" that Javascript will be logging
}
```

And add this function at the very beginning of your `<script>` tags:

```
function update_file(old_name, new_name) {
    var update = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Initialize the request
    update.open("GET", "?old_name=" + old_name + "&new_name=" + new_name, true);
    // Put the variables in the request which will be captured by php
    update.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText != null) {
                if(this.responseText){
                    console.log("Renamed successfully!");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Error renaming!");
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Not sent!!");
            }
        }
    };
    update.send();
}
```

Then change this section of the code to this:

```
    const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
    editables.forEach(el => {
        var curr = el.innerHTML;
        // Get the current value before it changes
        el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
            localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
            console.log(el.innerHTML);
            update_file(curr, el.innerHTML);
            // Call the XMLHttpRequest with the values
        })
    });
```

This should give you a head start on how to use XHR requests (that's if you don't use them) ... This is only because for you to get data from `javascript` to `php` it has to be through `GET` or `POST` ... but data from `php` to `javascript` is as easy as putting `php` tags with the value inside of it.

Also there are literally comments everywhere so you can read and understand how and why it works. Don't hesitate to ask for help.

### ----------

Ok, as you work on that, here's a tip -- within the `foreach` loop, you can echo a hidden input as so: `... <input type="hidden" name="directory-' . $counter . ' " value=" ' . pathinfo($path1, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . ' "/>` (assuming this code is inside the `foreach` loop) ... and also a same hidden input below it for the extension, since images may have different extensions --(PATHINFO_EXTENSION) then instead of "directory-(number)", you have "extension-(number)" ... then update the request to send also the extension and the directory -- [update_info(old_name, new_name, extension, directory)] ... meaning you also update the XHR request to send those too ... And on the php side, you just concatenate the directory with the file name and the extension received.

Now when it comes to actually getting the values from the hidden inputs, remember there is a counter, so based on the value of `el.id`, which ends with a specific number, you take the value of the hidden input which has a name ending with the same number (this is within the forEach loop) for example for the value of extension, take value whose **name** attribute starts with "extension-" and ends with the same value as the one for el.id ... do this as well for the directory

Another option is to take the `el.nextElementSibling.value` for the first hidden input and then the next one too, and those will be the values for directory and extension...
I can actually write all of them down in code but it won't be a learning process for you, happy coding :) ... Hope you can understand the concept in the above explanations

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand how it should work, now I only have problem with this path because I have main directory `images/` and there are some subdirectories in which photos can be stored so I'm trying to resolve it

Comment: I continue working on that today and I'm still not sure how to get those values from hidden inputs